# Alguna idea de como hacer que las últimas imágenes de la galería queden alineadas?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo la siguiente galería de imágenes, que las muestra según su tamaño, y requiero hacer que al final queden alineadas (Como en la parte superiror, una recta). Alguna idea de como hacerlo?

```
$(window).on('load',function(){
waterFall();
var dataInt={"data":[{"src":"0.jpg"},{"src":"1.jpg"},{"src":"2.jpg"},{"src":"3.jpg"}]};
$(window).on('scroll',function(){
    if(checkScrollSlide()){
        $.each(dataInt.data,function(key,value){
            var oBox=$('<div>').addClass('box').appendTo($('#main'));
            var oPic=$('<div>').addClass('pic').appendTo(oBox);
            $('<img>').attr('src','images/'+$(value).attr('src')).appendTo(oPic);
        });
        waterFall();
    }
});
});

function waterFall() {
   var $boxs=$('#main>div');
   var w=$boxs.eq(0).outerWidth();
   var cols=Math.floor($(window).width()/w);
   $("#main").width(w*cols).css('margin','0 auto');
   var hArr=[];
   $boxs.each(function(index,value){
    var h=$boxs.eq(index).outerHeight();
    if(index<cols){
        hArr.push(h);
    }else {
        minH=Math.min.apply(null,hArr);
        var minHeightIndex=$.inArray(minH,hArr);
        $(value).css({
            'position':'absolute',
            'top':minH+'px',
            'left':minHeightIndex*w+'px'
        });
        hArr[minHeightIndex]+=$boxs.eq(index).outerHeight();
    }
 });
}

function checkScrollSlide() {
   var $lastBox=$('#main>div').last();
   var lastBoxDis=$lastBox.offset().top+Math.floor($lastBox.outerHeight()/2);
   var scrollTop=$(window).scrollTop();
   var documentH=$(window).height();
   return (lastBoxDis<scrollTop+documentH)?true:false;

}
```

Comment: Prueba con los [*CSS flexbox*](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Muchas gracias de nuevo, voy a revisar la documentación.

Comment: Aún no lo he logrado, estoy buscando manera... Logre que todas las fotos lo hicieran pero debo lograr que sean las últmas tres.  Sí puedes darte una vuelta por acá https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/357513/c%c3%b3mo-cambiar-el-scroll-infinito-por-uno-finito te agradecería :)